# Polycom VVX500 not picking up provisioning server

Tags: networking, voip, polycom

The company called us regarding needing assistance with setting up a phone line they haven't used in a while Polycom line was initially using a USB wifi dongle so we requested to connect it directly to ethernet LAN line. Issue persists. Tried different Wall Jack. Issue persists

The customer states initially that a warning sign appears on the phone, therefore we proceeded with setting up the provisioning server as our server and the server type as HTTP. Saved configuration and rebooted phone. "Provisioning failed" message appears to which we double check configuration and setup once more. Red "X" sign appears as there is no connection on the phone.

Last online registration on Netsapiens 2021-06-12 10:43:18 Last online registration on our portal 2021-07-20 15:51:57

It usually connects first to Netsapiens before updating on the portal, so that's where it got odd. Customer states last time it worked was last week

Made Reset to Factory settings as the phone makes no attempt whatsoever to sync with our server. Attempted to provision server once again; issue persists.

Under IP address I see it's getting one through DHCP; first an APIPA connection then one provisioned by the DHCP of the carrier, however it still has no connection

According to the Polycom manual it appears as though that this might be a faulty device, but considering it connected to the server again on the 20th I wanted to see what I might have missed before advising to purchase a new one